# Angular 8 - firstChange vs isFirstChange() in SimpleChange class

Tags: angular

as in topic, where is the difference between prop firstChange and method isFirstChange?
Is there any advantage to use prop over the method(or method over prop)?
Both seem to return the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. The `isFirstChange()` function is semantically correct way to access the member property `firstChange`.

From the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.9/packages/core/src/interface/simple_change.ts#L18):

```js
export class SimpleChange {
  constructor(public previousValue: any, public currentValue: any, public firstChange: boolean) {}

  isFirstChange(): boolean {
    return this.firstChange;
  }
}
```